# Python API with JSOn

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

import requests
import json

```
BASE_URL = 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080'
updated_entity = {
"productName":"Araliya Basmathi Rice",
 "description":"White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically       grown.",
"category":"Rice",
"brand":"Araliya",
"expiredDate":"2023.05.04",
"manufacturedDate":"2022.02.20",
"batchNumber":324567,
"unitPrice":1020,
"quantity":200,
"createdDate":"2022.02.24"
}

 response = requests.GET(f"{BASE_URL}/api/products/", json=updated_entity)
 print(response.status_code)
 print(response.json())
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code?
I want to retrieve all the products from the API Server and print the total number of products currently stored in the server.

Comment: `I want to retrieve all the products [...]`: What happens instead?

Comment: What does the code print? I.e. the status code and the json

Comment: This code raises AttributeError. Please post the code you're actually running. Where is the documentation for the API? That will tell you what you need to do to achieve your objective

Comment: Base URL= http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080

Comment: {

    "message": "success",

    "data": [

        {

            "id": 85,

            "productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice",

            "description": "White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",

            "category": "Rice",

            "brand": "CIC",

            "expiredDate": "2023.05.04",

            "manufacturedDate": "2022.02.20",

            "batchNumber": 324567,

            "unitPrice": 1020,

            "quantity": 200,

            "createdDate": "2022.02.24"

        },

Comment: {

            "id": 86,

            "productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice",

            "description": "White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",

            "category": "Rice",

            "brand": "CIC",

            "expiredDate": "2023.05.04",

            "manufacturedDate": "2022.02.20",

            "batchNumber": 324567,

            "unitPrice": 1020,

            "quantity": 200,

            "createdDate": "2022.02.24"


        },

...

...

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to list the products you should do this:

```
import requests

URL = 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080/api/products'

with requests.get(URL) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    for item in response.json()['data']:
        print(item)
```

If you want to add/update an item then:

```
import requests

URL = 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080/api/products'

updated_entity = {
    "productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice",
    "description": "White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",
    "category": "Rice",
    "brand": "Araliya",
    "expiredDate": "2023.05.04",
    "manufacturedDate": "2022.02.20",
    "batchNumber": 324567,
    "unitPrice": 1020,
    "quantity": 299,
    "createdDate": "2022.02.24"
}

with requests.post(URL, json=updated_entity) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
```